# Crear, visualizar, buscar, modificar y eliminar un fichero.txt

Tags: visual-c++, c++98

El programa falla en el caso 4 y 5. Agradezco si pueden ayudarme y ver qué está mal. El programa arranca pero sucede que necesito modificar el registro....y nose realiza..!! CASO 4

En cambio en el CASO 5 debo eliminar un registro..pero no lo hace...... El REMOVE y RENAME nose ejecutan talvez hay otro comando para eliminar y modificar.:!!

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> //guardar fichero


int main()
{
    int cedula,opcion,Bcedula,edad,telefono,Ntelefono,Nedad;
    char nombre[10],apellido[10];
    ofstream Guardar;
    ifstream Leer;
    fstream Temp; //referencia aun archivo temporal
    Guardar.open("Fichero.txt",ios::app);
    while(true)
    {
        cout<<"%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%"<<endl;
        cout<<"1 GUARDAR"<<endl;
        cout<<"2 LEER"<<endl;
        cout<<"3 BUSCAR"<<endl;
        cout<<"4 MODIFICAR"<<endl;
        cout<<"5 ELIMINAR"<<endl;
        cout<<"6 SALIR"<<endl;
        cout<<"%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%"<<endl;
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<"Elija una opcion:"<<endl;
        cin>>opcion;

        switch(opcion)
        {
            case 1:
                {
                    system("cls");
                    cout<<"Ingrese Nombre: ";
                    cin>>nombre;
                    cout<<"Ingrese Apellido: ";
                    cin>>apellido;
                    cout<<"Ingrese la Edad en años: ";
                    cin>>edad;
                    cout<<"Ingrese Numero de Telefono: ";
                    cin>>telefono;
                    cout<<"Ingrese su numero de cedula: ";
                    cin>>cedula;
                    Guardar<<nombre<<" "<<apellido<<" "<<edad<<" "<<telefono<<" "<<cedula<<endl;
                    break;
                }
            case 2:
                {
                    system("cls");  
                    Leer.open("Fichero.txt");
                    Leer>>nombre>>apellido>>edad>>telefono;
                    while(!Leer.eof())
                    {
                        Leer>>cedula;
                        cout<<"----------------------------"<<endl;
                        cout<<"Nombre:    "<<nombre<<endl;
                        cout<<"Apellido:  "<<apellido<<endl;
                        cout<<"Edad:      "<<edad<<" anios"<<endl;
                        cout<<"Telefono:  "<<telefono<<endl;
                        cout<<"Cedula:    "<<cedula<<endl;
                        cout<<"----------------------------"<<endl;
                        cout<<endl;
                        Leer>>nombre>>apellido>>edad>>telefono;
                    }
                    Leer.close();
                    break;
                }
            case 3:
                {
                    system("cls");  
                    Leer.open("Fichero.txt");
                    Leer>>nombre>>apellido>>edad>>telefono;
                    bool encontrado=false;
                    cout<<"Ingrese su numero de cedula para buscar"<<endl;
                    cin>>Bcedula;
                    while(!Leer.eof())
                    {
                        Leer>>cedula;
                        if(cedula==Bcedula)
                        {
                            encontrado=true;
                            cout<<"----------------------------"<<endl;
                            cout<<"Nombre:    "<<nombre<<endl;
                            cout<<"Apellido:  "<<apellido<<endl;
                            cout<<"Edad:      "<<edad<<" anio"<<endl;
                            cout<<"Telefono:  "<<telefono<<endl;
                            cout<<"Cedula:    "<<cedula<<endl;
                            cout<<"----------------------------"<<endl;
                            cout<<endl;
                        }
                        Leer>>nombre>>apellido>>edad>>telefono;
                    }
                    if(encontrado==false)
                    {
                        cout<<"Cedula no encontrada"<<endl;
                    }
                    Leer.close();
                    break;
                }

            case 4:
                {
                    system("cls");  
                    Leer.open("Fichero.txt");//abre fichero original
                    Temp.open("Temp.txt");//abrimos el temporal tambn
                    Leer>>nombre>>apellido>>edad>>telefono;
                    bool encontrado=false;
                    cout<<"Ingrese clave a modificar"<<endl;
                    cin>>Bcedula;
                    while(!Leer.eof())
                    {
                        Leer>>cedula;
                        if(cedula==Bcedula)
                        {
                            encontrado=true;
                            cout<<"Nombre:    "<<nombre<<endl;
                            cout<<"Apellido:  "<<apellido<<endl;
                            cout<<"Edad :     "<<edad<<" anios"<<endl;
                            cout<<"Telefono:  "<<telefono<<endl;
                            cout<<"Cedula:    "<<cedula<<endl;
                            cout<<endl;
                            cout<<"Ingrese su Edad a modificar"<<endl;
                            cin>>Nedad;
                            cout<<"Ingrese nuevo numero de telefono"<<endl;
                            cin>>Ntelefono;
                            Temp<<nombre<<" "<<apellido<<" "<<Nedad<<" "<<Ntelefono<<" "<<cedula<<endl;
                            cout<<endl;
                            cout<<"Modificado"<<endl;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Temp<<nombre<<" "<<apellido<<" "<<edad<<" "<<telefono<<" "<<cedula<<endl;
                        }
                        Leer>>nombre>>apellido>>edad>>telefono;
                    }
                    if(encontrado==false)
                    {
                        cout<<"Cedula no encontrada"<<endl;
                    }
                    Leer.close();
                    Temp.close();
                    remove("Fichero.txt");
                    rename("Temp.txt","Fichero.txt");
                    break;
                }

            case 5:
                {
                    system("cls");
                    Leer.open("Fichero.txt");
                    Temp.open("Temp.txt");
                    Leer>>nombre>>apellido>>edad>>telefono;
                    bool encontrado=false;
                    cout<<"Ingrese clave a eliminar"<<endl;
                    cin>>Bcedula;
                    while(!Leer.eof())
                    {
                        Leer>>cedula;
                        if(cedula==Bcedula)
                        {
                            encontrado=true;
                            cout<<"Nombre:    "<<nombre<<endl;
                            cout<<"Apellido:  "<<apellido<<endl;
                            cout<<"Edad:      "<<edad<<endl;
                            cout<<"Telefono:  "<<telefono<<endl;
                            cout<<"Cedula:    "<<cedula<<endl;
                            cout<<endl;
                            cout<<"Eliminado"<<endl;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Temp<<nombre<<" "<<apellido<<" "<<edad<<" "<<telefono<<" "<<cedula<<endl;
                        }
                        Leer>>nombre>>apellido>>edad>>telefono;
                    }
                    if(encontrado==false)
                    {
                        cout<<"Clave no encontrada"<<endl;
                    }
                    Leerclose();
                    Tempclose();
                    remove("Fichero.txt");
                    rename("Temp.txt","Fichero.txt");

                    break;
                }

            case 6:
                {
                    system("cls");

                    break;
                }   
        }   
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hola @Acuario. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! ¿Cómo falla? ¿Te da algún error? ¿Cuál? Por favor agrega más detalle en tu pregunta. La idea es que puedas ayudar a que te ayuden. Tendrás muchas más chances de obtener una respuesta con un problema detallado que no requiera que alguien tenga que leer todo tu código para entender qué está pasando antes de poder responderte. Quizás te sea útil realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Comment: Exáctamente ¿Qué es lo qe "*falla en el caso 4 y 5*"? ¿Podrías compartir el error que te sale? o ¿Podrías describir el fallo? o mejor aún ¿Podrías desarrollar un ejemplo con menos código pero el mismo comportamiento? (para que sea más fácil analizar el problema).

Comment: El programa arranca pero sucede que necesito modificar el registro....y nose realiza..!! CASO 4

En cambio en el CASO 5 debo eliminar un registro..pero no lo hace......
El REMOVE y RENAME nose ejecutan talvez hay otro comando para eliminar y modificar.:!!

Answer (score 1):

Justo después que terminas de declarar tus variables haces lo siguiente:

```
Guardar.open("Fichero.txt",ios::app);
```

pero no lo cierras, he ahí el problema, lo que podrías hacer es mandar esa operación al case 1 para luego cerrarla
y te falto ponerle el o al `ofstream Temp;`

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que agregar la librería:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
```

Y en unos métodos tienes error pero es porque no les pusiste punto:

```
Leer.close();
Temp.close();
```